# how to convert S3ObjectInputStream to PushbackInputStream

Tags: java, excel, amazon-s3, apache-poi, inputstream

I am uploading an excel(xls) file to s3 and then another application should download that file from s3 and parse using Apache POI reader. The reader accepts `inputstream` type as the input but for proper parsing of the excel it expects `PushbackInputStream`. The inputstream i get from the file downloaded from s3 is of type `S3ObjectInputStream`. How do i convert `S3ObjectInputStream` to `PushbackInputStream`?

I tried directly passing the `S3ObjectInputStream` (since this is an `inputStream`) to `PushbackInputStream`, but it resulted in the following exception :

```
org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:147)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:96)
.....
.....
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: InputStream MUST either support mark/reset, or be wrapped as a PushbackInputStream
at org.springframework.batch.item.excel.poi.PoiItemReader.openExcelFile(PoiItemReader.java:82)
.....
```

I tried casting S3ObjectInputStream to PushbackInputStream, but it resulted in classcastexception.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectInputStream cannot be cast to java.io.PushbackInputStream
```

Anyone knows the solution for this

Comment: Did you try [creating a new PushBackInputStream from your S3 stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PushbackInputStream.html#PushbackInputStream(java.io.InputStream))?

Comment: @Gagravarr:  I am trying that approach.. but not been successful till now.. trying to figure out things.. do you think you can help me out here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solved my issue.

```
InputStream inputStream = s3object.getObjectContent(); 
PushbackInputStream pushbackInputStream = new PushbackInputStream(inputStream);
```